# Is this $this needed since we know the code is contained within the function

Tags: php, oop, this

If $this references its own instance of a class. Would it make a difference if it were omitted since we know what '$this' is references as its always within the instance created.

E.g.

```
Class examp {

Public Function getName($name) {

$this->$name=name; 

}
```

E.g. 2 with $this omitted

```
Class examp {

Public Function getName($name) {

$name=name;

}
```

Comment: ANd `$this->$name=name; ` shuld be `$this->name=$name; `

Comment: fristly: provide valid code. both examples are wrong. secondly: tell us what you want to do.

Comment: All sorts of wrong, why is a function called getSomething setting a value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This particular function, despite being incorrect as pointed out, is just for illustration purposes, the function itself does not need solving. What I was trying to understand was the need for '$this', but Ive the got the answer now..thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example `$this->name` will never point to the parameter, as you're explicitly referencing the property `name` of the current object `$this`.

As for the second example you're simply referencing the parameter, and this difference is one of the reasons `$this` is used/omitted.